# how to load java.util.properties object into spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a properties object having key and value need to set into spring context. which a bean is having a variable as `@Value(${key})`.

There is no property file in the web application.

Can someone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the @Resource annotation to bind a properties file into Java.

```
@Resource (name="propertiesMapName") 
public Properties someProps;
```

In your XML files

xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd

...
<util:properties id="propertiesMapName" location="classpath:yourFile.properties"/>
```

Comment: as i said there is no property file, programmatically need to add the properties object in spring context, so i can refer the value as @Value("key")

Comment: @user1702759 you cant do that, you cant add programatically some value is needed to start up spring context (@Value("key"))